# Crashlytics for crashes on device not reporting on firebase console

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I am able to see crashes caused from simulator but when I create adhoc build and install on device and then crash it (made sure to relaunch after crash), it's not reporting at all. I have already waited for a week and there are enough crashes.

I am only surprised why its is reporting with simulator and why not for adhoc builds. What's difference in terms of crash reporting for simulator vs for device. I have already tried all solution available but not able to see crash logs for DEVICE only.

It's been one week I trying my own and reached to dead end , please help in this regard.
Thanks.

- My firebase setup

  ```
  "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.0.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.5", //<========
  "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^8.4.9",//<===========
  "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^7.9.0",
  "@react-native-firebase/perf": "^7.4.8",
  "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^7.0.10",
  ```
- **Console**

[image: Here is the output, notice only simulator logs]

**Notice - All the crashes are only for simulator.**

- **Build Options**

[image: Build Options]

- **Scheme Configuration while archiving**

[image: Scheme]

- Build Phase
  [image]

Note - I have also uploaded DSYMS from archive to make sure have some thing to do with missing dsyms.

Comment: How do you distribute your adhoc IPA file? Do you have any other crash reporting tool attached to your app?

Comment: I will add as an answer, strangely when we share our app through azure app centre we have made process to upload from there entire zip containing more than one DSYM (strange). We were only uploading one appName-dsym. react native hell

Comment: So did you end up uploading all dSYMs and did the crashes come in then?

Comment: uploading all the dsym from a single IPA (sounds confusing but yes). NOT ALL THE DSYMS FOR ALL RELEASES!!!

Comment: You can manually run the upload-symbols script to upload all dSYMs on per app basis

Comment: Yes exactly that what I did only thing strange my single app contain more than once dsym. I experienced it react native project only. I was uploading only one dsym as per my native experience, however in react native generate ipa there is more than one dsym in single release.